# el desfile - la desfile?

Tags: género

En un episido de Netflix, Hilda, dos personajes usaban la palabra desfile, pero con dos géneros diferentes...

A: "Bueno, alguien va al desfile de esta noche?"

B: "Las desfiles son para los niños..."

Sé que algunos sustantivos cambian del sentido depende del género del articulo definido (el mar/la mar) pero no he podido encontrar nada acerca de este tipo de uso con 'desfile'.  Y lo que me da más curiosidad aún es la rapidez del cambio.  Fue a propósito, como para contradecir la primera?

Algunas ideas?

---

### Inglés

In an episode of Hilda (Netflix), two characters, both female (though likely *their* gender isn't relevant) used 'desfile' but with different genders, in back to back lines:

A: "Bueno, alguien va al desfile de esta noche?"

B: "Las desfiles son para los niños..."

I know certain words have different meanings when changing their gender (el mar/la mar, etc.) but can't find anything about desfile even being an option like this, nor why someone might change the gender so quickly of a previously uttered noun.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's just a typo. *Desfile* is always masculine.

Comment: Was this originally in Spanish?  Dubbed?  Was the Spanish only available as subtitles?

Comment: I have seen many shows/movies where multiple languages are used (Breaking Bad, Daredevil, Jack Ryan ...) and the "quality" of the non-English language spoken varies wildly. Sometimes the actor is not fluent in Spanish and you can tell. Sometimes they only need to _sound_ like Spanish (it's TV, after all). Sometimes subtitles don't really match the audio or have typos. Of course, I'm able to tell when it happens in Spanish, but if they spoke Chinese, everything would look fine to me. Bottom line, great question, it's good that you checked, but it may be just a typo / "flaw" in the TV script

Comment: Not a typo. This was spoken not written.  In fact, I rarely use subtitles because they often are completely different.  When I put the subtitles on to double check, desfile was mentioned by A but not even uttered by B. 

I thought to use Audacity to make a clip of the sound but thought that might be overkill as well and thought someone might have some bizarre use case for la desfile. Or perhaps it was a gender change as a means of making it sound more childish (reaching at this point lol...).

Comment: Diego, you should use that comment as an answer. I’d like to mark it as best.  It’s a quality point that the voice actors could have made a mistake.  Obviously I searched DRAE before and know desfile is a masculine noun so your comment gives reason as to why this might have happened.

Answer (score 5):

Me parece que es un error. Si buscas la palabra [desfile](https://dle.rae.es/desfile?m=form) en el diccionario de la Real Academia Española te darás cuenta de que el único género que se le puede asignar a la palabra "desfile" es masculino. Por lo tanto, sería "el desfile".

Answer (score 0):

It's an error, desfile does not accept both genders